# Ruby simple class issue

Tags: ruby, class

I've got to the point that it is seems to be working but it is not ...

```
class Person1
  def initialize (name, surname, age)
    @name = name
    @surname = surname
    @age = age
  end

  def introduction
    p @name
    p @surname
    p @age
  end
end
```

I call it:

```
ken = Person1.new ("Ken", "Bolo", 4)
ken.introduction
```

and have an argument with the compiler regarding the amount of parameters I'm passing to instantiate my object. With 3 it is telling me that I have to many, with 2 it is telling me it is too many, with 1 it is telling me it is too little ! Nuts!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simply remove the space between `Person1.new` and `("Ken", "Bolo", 4)` or remove the parenthesis: `Person1.new "Ken", "Bolo", 4`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: the initializer definition suffers from the same problem

Comment: Never ever put a space between method name and opening parenthesis. Trust us on this one. Later you'll know why :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I hadn't notice the space after `initialize`, but, curiously, that one does not seem to be a problem. Can you explain why?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `def a (b) ; b end` and `a (1) #=> 1` works. I would also like to know why and how this can cause a trouble? thx!

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: add a second parameter. :) You seriously don't know or just trolling or something?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: huh. I could swear it didn't work some time ago. Let me quickly install an older ruby and check.

Comment: [Here](http://www.justskins.com/forums/ruby-1-8-space-122361.html) are some words on this subject delivered by a wise man from the land of the rising sun (though not definitive).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I seriously don't know. Could you please point me to some good article on the topic? (I never faced the issue before cause I never left a space between method name and parenthesis).

Comment: @AndreyDeineko: ["It's caused by limitation of yacc pr generator (and my brain).
Please stand, and don't put spaces before argument parentheses, please.

matz."](http://www.justskins.com/forums/ruby-1-8-space-122361.html)

Comment: Ah, Cary beat me to it. How can it be any more definitive, though? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i've read this before you updated the comment (which made total sense to me) - thanks!

Comment: BTW, with ruby 2.3.1 I'm not getting any "too many arguments" errors. I'm getting "syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'"

Comment: Seems like whitespace after the method name is simply ignored if followed by `(`, i.e. `def foo (a, b)` is equivalent to `def foo(a, b)` and therefore valid. `def foo (a), b` is equivalent to `def foo(a), b` and therefore invalid. `def foo a, (b)` on the other hand is equivalent to `def foo(a, (b))` which is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the whitespace between the method name and the parentheses:

```
class Person1
  def initialize(name, surname, age)
    @name = name
    @surname = surname
    @age = age
  end

  def introduction
    p @name
    p @surname
    p @age
  end
end

ken = Person1.new("Ken", "Bolo", 4)
ken.introduction
#=> "Ken"
#=> "Bolo"
#=> 4
```

Comment: OK, spickermann, the [ball's in your court](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+ball+is+in+court). Why is a space permitted in some situations and not others?

Comment: Easy: it *is* permitted: `foo.bar (a; b; c)` is perfectly fine, for example. Parentheses are for parameter lists, argument lists (if they appear directly after a message send), and grouping, in this case, they group three expressions together. In the OP's case, the grouped expression is `"Ken", "Bolo", 4`, which is simply not a syntactically legal expression. BTW: this exact same question (and answer) has already been posted several times on SO. Most of the duplicates have better, more detailed explanations than this one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, it seems like I introduced a red herring by noting that the second space in `def initialize (name, surname, age)` was OK. Of course it's OK--it's part of a method definition, not the arguments of a method being invoked. Is that second space permitted because it introduces no ambiguity?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There are two ways of passing arguments to a message send: 1) with parentheses following directly after the message name, and 2) with whitespace. The OP chose option #2: passing arguments with whitespace. How many arguments did he pass? Well, we use parentheses to group expressions, so a parenthesized expression counts as one expression, ergo, he passed one argument. But the method takes three. Also, the argument he *did* pass is syntactically invalid. All of this is explained much better in one of the many dupes of this question that already exist.